# Should you check the return code from Getopt::Long::GetOptions?

Tags: perl, getopt, getopt-long

I've just been asked for the first time in a code review to check the return code from a call to the `GetOptions()` function of the `Getopt::Long` Perl module.

I cannot remember ever seeing such a test for the `GetOptions()` function.

So is there a specific reason why people don't generally check the return code of this function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One reason that people don't check the return value of the `GetOptions` function is that they want to process unspecified options without using [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html)  (by parsing `@ARGV` directly after `GetOptions` is called).  Or, maybe they just want to ignore unspecified options.  Or, maybe they are unaware that the `GetOptions` function can fail.

I always check the return value because I like to catch typos on the command line.  A standard way to check makes use of the [Pod::Usage](http://perldoc.perl.org/Pod/Usage.html) Core module (see the POD for example code).  See also: [The Dynamic Duo --or-- Holy Getopt::Long, Pod::UsageMan!](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=155288)

Comment: I usually check the return value of `GetOptions` if I want to make the programm `die` on errors when parsing command line arguments. Like `die unless GetOptions(...)`. If not `pass_trough` is still an option to catch the rest of the arguments in `@ARGV`.

Comment: Cheers @toolic for the very useful answer. I didn't think of misspelled options. And big thanks for the link to the article providing more info abut why I should add more pod to my Perl!